# Using USB HDD with Arcserve / Brightstor

Tags: usb, backup

I am having an issue configuring a standard USB HDD for use with CA Arcserve Brightstor 11.5 SP2 :

Under the device list it shows a USB device category but none of my USB drives are listed underneath. I have attempted to "scan devices" but it makes no difference.

I have also tried restarting the tape engine to no avail! Is anyone successfully using USB drives with Brightstor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many different setups over the past month but have not had any success. I can get the backup to run (using a File System Device), alternating between 2 usb drives but when I try a test restore using the previous day's disk it complains that it can't find the file due to the "session being truncated"

In all practicality I don't think Brightstor 11.5 can handle backing up to usb hdds. Grrr